# why ziparchive does not work from stdin

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am trying to use ziparchive to unzip..I am doing it this way:

> 1) send a zip file to email address
>
> 2) pipe that email to a php file
>
> 3) php file will process email, parse it, decode it and save it in
>   text file
>
> 4) php will move on with ziparchive (to unzip file above)

I got 1-4 working but i am having issue at step 4..but its strange..from stdin, it does not work; no error, no warnings but in step 3, i am saving text file so if i feed that text file in shell command:

```
cat textfile | ./myphp.php
```

Then it works but why it does not work from stdin?

Comment: there are more than ∞ probably reason , and it will be really hard to help without any clues , provide your code which is related to your issue;